# JTable RowSorter order wrong

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablerowsorter

I imported javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;

used it in the table model. It works properly with Strings, but with numbers it orders everything in a weird way, as shown in the picture. I'm a noob at coding so I don't really know how to properly google for such an issue yet.

[image]

```
 DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
 table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
```

Not sure if you still need more code. It is a mess tbh, as object oriented coding came up in school after i started this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your sorting is doing an alphabetical sort, which works well for `String` objects, but once you have `Integers` to sort, you will have the situation that 2 > 19, because alphabetically 2 is after 1.

You will need something like:

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data,columns) {
    @Override
    public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
        switch (column) {
            case 4: {
                //assuming that the int column you have is in the fourth column
                return Integer.class; 
            } break;
            default:
                return String.class;
        }
    }
};
```

where `data` is an `Object[][]` and `columns` is an `Object[]`.

Comment: So i have to create a case for every column? Do I understand that right?

Comment: @Mackey The default is a `String`, so you will need to make a case for any non-String column where you intend to support sorting and alphabetic sort is undesired.